# Python Executable created with pyinstaller fails because of gdal

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gdal

I am trying to create an executable with pyinstaller from a python project. The project uses osgeo modules gdal and osr:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr
```

pyinstaller runs successfully, but when I try to execute the file I encounter the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "osgeo_*init*_.py", line
> 29, in swig_import_helper   File "importlib_*init*_.py", line 127, in
> import_module   File "", line 1030, in
> _gcd_import   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo._gdal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "[...].py", line 1, in
>    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495,
> in exec_module   File "[...]_*init*_.py", line 1, in    File
> "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
> File "[...]\GeoMap.py", line 1, in    File
> "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
> File "osgeo_*init*_.py", line 45, in    File
> "osgeo_*init*_.py", line 41, in swig_import_helper ImportError:
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "osgeo_*init*_.py", line
> 29, in swig_import_helper   File "importlib_*init*_.py", line 127, in
> import_module   File "", line 1030, in
> _gcd_import   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo._gdal'
>
> On Windows, with Python >= 3.8, DLLs are no longer imported from the
> PATH. If gdalXXX.dll is in the PATH, then set the
> USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES environment variable to feed the PATH
> into os.add_dll_directory(). [3268] Failed to execute script '[removed
> name]' due to unhandled exception!

I am using Python 3.9 and pyinsatller 5.0.1, gdal 3.4.2.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and found a solution?